# Adding additional arguments to a shell script with optional args

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

I have a shell script which takes 1 mandatory argument and upto 3 optional arguments and I want to enhance the script by able to pass one more additional argument without breaking the current design .
That is if my argument is n and existing arguments are a and b c and d  the following should work

```
./script.sh a b c d n
./script.sh a n
./script.sh a b n
./script.sh a b c n
```

Comment: OK. what *is* your current design?

Comment: a1=$1
a2=$2
a3=$3
a4=$4

var=($a1 $a2 $a3 $a4)

for i in ${var[*]}

Comment: @sudeep, use `"${var[@]}"` for iterating over arrays -- `${var[*]}` concatenates into a scalar, then string-splits and glob-expands it.

Comment: ...to see what that means in practice, try passing a single argument with `"two words"`.

Comment: How about: `var=( "$@" )` -- then you can have however many arguments you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the last argument is `n`.  If so, remove it from the argument list and add the rest to an array, else add all the arguments to an array.

```
if [[ "${@: -1}" = n ]]; then
  for j in "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"; do
    var+=($j)
  done
else
  for j; do
    var+=($j)
  done
fi

echo "${var[@]}"
```

This would produce:

```
a b c
```

when the arguments to the script are `a b c` and `a b c n`.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but straightforward:

```
case $# in
    0|1) printf >&2 "Too few arguments\n"; exit 1
         ;;
    2) first=$1
       second=$2
       ;;
    3) first=$1
       optional_a=$2
       second=$3
       ;;
    4) first=$1
       optional_a=$2
       optional_b=$3
       second=$4
       ;;
    5) first=$1
       optional_a=$2
       optional_b=$3
       optional_c=$4
       second=$5
       ;;
    *) printf >&2 "Too many optional arguments\n"; exit 1
       ;;
esac
```

The two required arguments are in `first` and `second`; the three optional arguments are in `optional_a`, `optional_b`, and `optional_c`, respectively.